# What can I do to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I think there is some confusion regarding my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658048/time-asymmetry-in-newtonian-mechanics?) (which is not obvious to me). And for now it has $4$ downvotes and $2$ upvotes (and the comment section has become a mess).

Can someone enlighten me as to what I can do to write the question clearer?

Comment: Note: the question is currently hidden from users without the [moderator tools privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). You can undelete it to get feedback from more users.